# How to configure a list of technologies in start menu in Intellij Idea when I press "new project"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I press "new project", I want to add some sections (for example, JBoss or Spring section) in this list of technologies (sorry, idk how to say it rightly, look at the photo). How can I do it? I use Ultimate version of Intellij Idea

Currently:

[image: my photo: list in my new project]

I want my list to be like this:

[image: I want my list to be like this]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to write your own IntelliJ plugin for that ([SDK Docs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-started.html?from=jetbrains.org)).
If you just want to create a project-template (not a whole category) you may follow these instructions (which is a lot simpler than creating a plugin): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-projects-in-product.html#ws_create_project_from_saved_template

Comment: I added one more picture, look at the photo again, please

Comment: The photo you added looks like an older version of IntelliJ (I assume you have that from a tutorial or something similar). For Spring you should use the `Spring Initializr`-Section to create a new project. For JBoss I unfortunately do not know where that went. But in general I suggest you look if there is a plugin for the framework you want to use (Settings>Plugins>Marketplace). E.g. for "ktor" there is a plugin that adds a section for creating such projects. Maybe there is one for JBoss as well and it just is not bundled anymore?

Comment: It's possible to do now, but there are no plugins for spring or JBoss. It's already installed but i can't see it in my list in "new project"